# How to write a JSP which renders a list of JSP fragments, without IF switching code

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a JSP which composes a List of Objects, then renders JSP fragments depending on the Class of each of the objects in the List.
At the moment, this is done with a huge chain of if statements inside the 'parent' JSP:

```
   if( bean.getFilterChildByType( Level.class ) != null )
   {
   %> <jsp:include page="filters/level.jsp"/> <% 
   }
   if( bean.getFilterChildByType( Sources.class ) != null )
   {
   %> <jsp:include page="filters/sources.jsp"/> <% 
   }
   ...
```

So, my question is, in JSP (Tomcat) is it possible to achieve this same functionality without an if chain, just by iterating the Objects in the list and perhaps taking advantage of the naming convention "Class name".jsp ?  I've played with:

```
<%@ include file="filename" %>
```

but this doesn't seem to allow variables in the file-name either.

Comment: Are you accessing the 'main' jsp directly via URL or are you forwarding/including via a servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
<jsp:include page="filters/<%=filename%>.jsp"/>
```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: File "/access/filters/<%=filename%>.jsp" not found

Comment: I found out why this didn't work!  "As per the JSP include sytanx you can use either the include-file-name in quotes directly or you can give it as a variable within scriptlet tags but not as a combination of both." So, I needed to do: <jsp:include page="<%=filename%>"/> where filename = 'filters/myfile.jsp'

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the appropriate jsp to be included (based on `bean.getFilterChildByType`) at the controller side and then just pass the name of the jsp to the container jsp. Now this can be easily included.

Comment: please explain how the passed parameter can be used to include a JSP

Comment: pass the jsp name to include as a request parameter

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one!

If the included jsp files (level.jsp, source.jsp, etc) are not too complex, what about shifting the HTML from those files over to a function call of the objects you are calling bean.getFilterChildByType(...) on?

That way, instead of a large if/else tree, you could then just call:

```
String html = bean.getHtmlForType();
```

...would likely work out much cleaner in a loop too.

Comment: usually, keeping the view state at java side is a bad idea

Comment: Perhaps, however, the way that the author seems to be using the JSPs shows that the JSPs are directly related to an object type.  One could possibly assert, then, that the JSP represents part of the object's state.  That's the only reason why I'd even mention having java generate HTML.

Normally, I'm right there with you in keeping the model and view separate.